# Enable alarm in Shortcuts

Tags: iphone, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I'd like to create a bedtime shortcut, which activates my alarms and activate Do Not Disturb on my iPhone.

When I choose the clock app inside the Shortcut creator, I only have the option create alarm, which creates a new alarm every time I run the shortcut.

[image]

I want to activate an existing alarm and not create an copy of an existing one.

Comment: You’re closer than I am! I can’t even see the Clock app.

Comment: I have heard about that Problem.

Comment: It seems that toggling a few of my alarms in the Clock app made them appear in Shortcuts.

Comment: Hi guys, I've posted below an answer with a link to a shortcut with only the `Edit Bedtime` as an object. Can you let me know if installing the shortcut, selecting the object and tapping on `Favorite` has the effect of making it available in your Favorites tab in your Shortcuts app? Thanks in advance! (P.S. I got it from Siri Suggestions, maybe because I `Edit Bedtime` a lot of the time. (pretty much daily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts is using often used actions you made on you phone. so if you create an alarm and turn it on and of a few times, you will be able to enable it in shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

When Shortcuts first came out, I immediately created a `Sleepytimes` script. Among other things, it enabled `Do Not Disturb`. After some days of use, I realised that you could also add controls over Bedtime.

The two steps you are looking to do go like this.

1. Add the object `Set Do Not Disturb`. Set it to `ON` and the Until to your liking.
2. Add the object `Edit Bedtime` (search for it - if you cannot find it, just launch Clock -> Bedtime a couple of times - hopefully there will be an easier way to get this to show in the future).

Hope this helps! Also, I think I can just share a shortcut with `Edit Bedtime` in it. Let me know if you are able to access `Edit Bedtime` by opening this iCloud link - after that you could try and tap on the object and select "Set favorite". Would be interesting to see if this lets it show for you from now on in the searches or in the Favorite -tab?

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/54661787f1584383bf2c369507222382

[image: Set Do Not Disturb and Edit Bedtime]

Comment: Nice answer which works but not the solution of my Problem, I found a way. I will describe it in an answer.